# How to delete columns in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, row-removal

I have been able to create a csv with python using the input from several users on this site and I wish to express my gratitude for your posts.  I am now stumped and will post my first question.

My input.csv looks like this:

```
day,month,year,lat,long
01,04,2001,45.00,120.00
02,04,2003,44.00,118.00
```

I am trying to delete the "year" column and all of its entries.  In total there is 40+ entries with a range of years from 1960-2010.

Comment: This is the type of problem where `awk` shines: `$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$4,$5}' ex.csv`

Comment: @Eric Wilson: Luckily, this CSV file has no quotes, allowing AWK to work.

Comment: @S.Lott I agree, when the CSV format gets more complicated, Python's `csv` is the way to go. I only use `awk` when it clearly works, and is only one line.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
import csv
with open("source","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow( (r[0], r[1], r[3], r[4]) )
```

BTW, the `for` loop can be removed, but not really simplified.

```
        in_iter= ( (r[0], r[1], r[3], r[4]) for r in rdr )
        wtr.writerows( in_iter )
```

Also, you can stick in a hyper-literal way to the requirements to delete a column.  I find this to be a bad policy in general because it doesn't apply to removing more than one column.  When you try to remove the second, you discover that the positions have all shifted and the resulting row isn't obvious.  But for one column only, this works.

```
            del r[2]
            wtr.writerow( r )
```

Comment: This one worked nearly flawlessly, an error came up regarding the syntax.  The colon should be deleted from wtr=csv.writer(result) Thanks for your input on this it has helped, it is also handy because it works on any number of columns I may need to delete.

Comment: You can easily use your second method for multiple columns by deleting the highest column first, e.g.
'del r[8]
 del r[6]
 del r[2]
 wtr.writerow(r)'

Comment: You can save some writing for bigger CSV's by replacing `(r[0], r[1], r[3], r[4])` with something like `tuple(r[ii] for ii in range(len(r)) if ii != 2)`

Comment: To delete more than 1 column in your last point, can't you just use the classic delete 'em backwards workaround?

Answer (score 52):

Use of Pandas module will be much easier.

```
import pandas as pd
f=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
keep_col = ['day','month','lat','long']
new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("newFile.csv", index=False)
```

And here is short explanation:

```
>>>f=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
>>> f
   day  month  year  lat  long
0    1      4  2001   45   120
1    2      4  2003   44   118
>>> keep_col = ['day','month','lat','long'] 
>>> f[keep_col]
    day  month  lat  long
0    1      4   45   120
1    2      4   44   118
>>>
```

Comment: This works even if your csv has line breaks in a string on the the row - many other linux commands like `cut` fail to remove columns and maintain the data integrity when a row's field has a line break as part of the content of the csv

Comment: In my case, the integer are get converted to float.

Comment: @Gunarathinam you can prevent this in newer pandas versions by passing `dtype=str` to `read_csv`

Answer (score 6):

Using a dict to grab headings then looping through gets you what you need cleanly.

```
import csv
ct = 0
cols_i_want = {'cost' : -1, 'date' : -1}
with open("file1.csv","rb") as source:
    rdr = csv.reader( source )
    with open("result","wb") as result:
        wtr = csv.writer( result )
        for row in rdr:
            if ct == 0:
              cc = 0
              for col in row:
                for ciw in cols_i_want: 
                  if col == ciw:
                    cols_i_want[ciw] = cc
                cc += 1
            wtr.writerow( (row[cols_i_want['cost']], row[cols_i_want['date']]) )
            ct += 1
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use Pandas with `col number`

```
f = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=[0,1,3,4])
f.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly delete the column with just

```
del variable_name['year']
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It says it requires an integer since it expects and index

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `csv` package to iterate over your csv file and output the columns that you want to another csv file.

The example below is not tested and should illustrate a solution:

```
import csv

file_name = 'C:\Temp\my_file.csv'
output_file = 'C:\Temp\new_file.csv'
csv_file = open(file_name, 'r')
## note that the index of the year column is excluded
column_indices = [0,1,3,4]
with open(output_file, 'w') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
       tmp_row = []
       for col_inx in column_indices:
           tmp_row.append(row[col_inx])
       fh.write(','.join(tmp_row))
```

Comment: Dispense with the the `tmp_row` and the `join` and use `csv.writer` and a generator expression:  `for row in reader: wtr.writerow(row[i] for i in column_indices)`.  It's safer (handles quoting automatically), more concise, and faster.

Comment: Why not use `csv` for writing, also?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, this will do it without any sort of error checking nor ability to configure anything. That is "left to the reader".

```
outFile = open( 'newFile', 'w' )
for line in open( 'oldFile' ):
   items = line.split( ',' )
   outFile.write( ','.join( items[:2] + items[ 3: ] ) )
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I will add yet another answer to this question. Since the OP did not say they needed to do it with Python, the fastest way to delete the column (specially when the input file has hundreds of thousands of lines), is by using `awk`.

**This is the type of problem where awk shines:**

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$4,$5}' input.csv
```

(feel free to append `> output.csv` to the command above if you need the output to be saved to a file)

Credit goes 100% to @eric-wilson who provided this awesome answer, as a comment on the original question, 10 years ago, almost without any credit.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
result= data.drop('year', 1)
result.head(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try python with pandas and exclude the column, you don't want to have:

```
import pandas as pd

# the ',' is the default separator, but if your file has another one, you have to define it with sep= parameter
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", sep=',')
exclude_column = "year"
new_df = df.loc[:, df.columns != exclude_column]
# you can even save the result to the same file
new_df.to_csv("input.csv", index=False, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

My take using pandas's `drop` in python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("old.csv")
new_df = df.drop("year", axis=1)
new_df.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you store the parsed CSV, but generally you want the del operator.

If you have an array of dicts:

```
input = [ {'day':01, 'month':04, 'year':2001, ...}, ... ]
for E in input: del E['year']
```

If you have an array of arrays:

```
input = [ [01, 04, 2001, ...],
          [...],
          ...
        ]
for E in input: del E[2]
```