# How to extract named columns from a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that contains around 50 columns, but I only need about 10 of them. I want to be able to extract the columns I need from that csv file to a new csv file.

The top answer in this post [How to delete columns in a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588934/deleting-columns-in-a-csv-with-python) looks like it will do exactly what I need.

BUT this is something I will need to do daily, and the system that generates the big CSV file can export the columns in different orders. So I need to be able to specify the columns I need by name, rather than by number.

The following is indicative of the CSV files:

File1.csv

```
name, description, cost, image, date
ABC, "super, mega", 12.87, ./imagefile, "12/11/2012 08:12"
```

File2.csv

```
name, cost, date, description, image
SYZ, 43.98, "16/11/2012 09:16", "Some text, and such", ./image2.jpeg
```

I want to keep the name, description and image fields only, but if I use the code (derived form the post above by [@S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott)):

```
import csv
with open("source","rb") as source:
rdr= csv.reader( source )
with open("result","wb") as result:
    wtr= csv.writer( result )
    for r in rdr:
        wtr.writerow( (r[0], r[1], r[3]) )
```

It will only work for the first file and not the second.

Comment: Are you assured the column names won't change?  One day "image", the next, "img"?

Comment: The column names will not change, they will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Read it in using the [DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class, then you can write out fields by name instead of by index.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this is that not only it makes easy to open and save your files in different formats and modify columns and rows, but also because you can also modify, calculate and play with your data if you need it.

To obtain a csv file with selected columns is straighforward:

```
import pandas as p

df = p.read_csv('File2.csv')  # reads your csv file as a table (dataframe object)

df2 = df[['cost', 'date']]    # selects two of the columns in your file

df2.to_csv('my_out.csv')      # saves again in csv format
```