# How to pull two columns (with headers) from CSV and show them side by side?

Tags: python, csv

I apologize if this has already been covered, but I did spend a bit of time looking for this answer on the site.

I am looking for a way to pull two columns out of a csv file (the only two of about twenty) that are important to my project) and display them.

The result should be like so (where `server` and `warranty` are two columns separated by several more):

```
Server    Warranty  
DP123     Current  
DP124     Current  
DP125     Expired
```

Comment: maybe look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410746/extract-named-columns-from-a-csv-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the the [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function from the [pandas data analysis library](https://pandas.pydata.org/), define the subset of disired columns as a list and hand that to the 'usecols' function parameter:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv', usecols=['Server','Warranty'])

print(df)
```