# remove multiple columns

Tags: csv, multiple-columns

I am trying to remove multiple columns at one time without utilizing their field info.  I get a CSV file from the county each month and there are multiple fields that I do not wish to share with the general public.  Up until now, each month I manually delete each field.  Since I am attempting to learn python, I would like to learn how to create a script to do it.  There are 58 fields that I want to delete, so I don't want to write a script for each one but am hoping to create a range for deleting them.  I have been searching the forums here for a few hours and have tried so many different methods that I don't know where to start or stop.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this
[Deleting columns - python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588934/deleting-columns-in-a-csv-with-python

Comment: I did look at that.  I have over 100 fields that I want to retain, so I am trying not to list each of them out.  Unless I am misunderstanding all of the suggestions for that post, that is what I would need to do.  I am willing to list them all but would rather avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 6):

I'm lazy, so I like to use existing libraries when I can, and have become something of an evangelist for the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.  Using @Tim Pietzcker's example:

```
Name,Sex,Address,Age
John,M,New York,40
Mary,F,Los Angeles,30
```

We can keep only the columns we want using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("to_remove.csv")
keep_cols = ["Name", "Address"]
new_df = df[keep_cols]
new_df.to_csv("removed.csv", index=False)
```

(We could also one-line it, but I think it's clearer like that.)

---

Explanation follows.  First, we can read the file into a storage object called a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("to_remove.csv")
>>> df
   Name Sex      Address  Age
0  John   M     New York   40
1  Mary   F  Los Angeles   30
```

We can select one or multiple columns from this object:

```
>>> df[["Name", "Sex"]]
   Name Sex
0  John   M
1  Mary   F
```

And then write it out:

```
>>> new_df = df[["Name", "Sex"]]
>>> new_df.to_csv("removed.csv", index=False)
```

(the `index=False` bit just tells it not to add a column counting the rows, the numbers 0, 1 above), producing

```
Name,Sex
John,M
Mary,F
```

We can also decide that we only want to keep columns starting with the letter "A":

```
>>> [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("A")]
['Address', 'Age']
>>> df[[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("A")]]
       Address  Age
0     New York   40
1  Los Angeles   30
```

or use the `.ix` method to keep only the columns from #1 to the next-to-last:

```
>>> df.ix[:,1:-1]
  Sex      Address
0   M     New York
1   F  Los Angeles
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a CSV file like this:

```
Name,Sex,Address,Age
John,M,New York,40
Mary,F,Los Angeles,30
```

and you want to *keep* only the columns `Name` and `Address`.

Then you can do something like this (Python 3), making use of the `extrasignore` parameter of the `DictWriter` class:

```
import csv
fields = ["Name", "Address"]

with open("test.csv") as infile, open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    #           in Python 2, use open("out.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```

Result:

```
Name,Address
John,New York
Mary,Los Angeles
```

If you want to do it the other way around, i. e. specify which columns to *delete*  from the file, then it's a bit more complicated:

```
import csv
delete = ["Sex", "Age"]

with open("test.csv") as infile, open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    #           in Python 2, use open("out.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    firstrow = next(r)  # Need to read the first row so we know the fieldnames
    fields = r.fieldnames
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, 
                       [field for field in fields if not field in delete], 
                       extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(firstrow)
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
```