# Delete data in csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files with a single column of data. How can I remove data in the second csv file in-place by comparing it with the data in the first csv file? For example:

```
 import csv
 reader1 = csv.reader(open("file1.csv", "rb")) 
 reader = csv.reader(open("file2.csv", "rb"))f
 for line in reader:
     if line in reader1:
         print line
```

[image: File 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting columns in a CSV with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588934/deleting-columns-in-a-csv-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if both files are just single columns, then you could use `set` to remove the differences. However, this presumes that the entries in each file do not need to be duplicated and their order doesn't really matter.

```
#since each file is a column, unroll each file into a single list:
dat1 = [x[0] for x in reader1]
dat2 = [y[0] for y in reader]

#take the set difference
dat1_without_dat2 = set(dat1).difference(dat2)
```

Comment: the result is exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cvs.py", line 8, in <module>
    dat1 = [x[[0]] for x in reader1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: should be fixed now, sorry, i was just helping someone with `R` hence `x[[0]]` which is wrong. `x[0]` , `y[0]`, should work