# How would I make a program that removes all of the letters and the commas after them from a txt document?

Tags: python, text

I have a giant text document that looks sort of like this:

```
A,1,2,3
B,2,5,3
C,7,9,0
.
.
.
```

How would I write a program that would make the text document look like this:

```
1 2 3
2 5 3
7 9 0
.
.
.
```

(Basically the letters and the commas after the letter are removed, and all commas after the first number change into spaces)

Comment: Is it a simple CSV file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting columns in a CSV with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588934/deleting-columns-in-a-csv-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to call the following on each line:

```
line.split(',')[1:]
```

This splits the line along the commas, and then slices off the first element.

Comment: This didn't really work. The new lines ended up being the same as the old ones

Comment: That's because the code is incomplete and meant more as a hint, I presume.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux/Unix you can use basic shell commands, which should be available everywhere:

```
cut -d "," -f 2- --output-delimiter=" " input.txt > output.txt
```

If you insist on using Python, you can do:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(' '.join(line.split(',')[1:]))
```