# How to remove the first column in data frame before to convert to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have just a simple code that converts the `txt` file to `csv`, as now I want to delete the first column that's with no name as shown in the below figure:

[image]

and this is my simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os



hua_umts_dataf_rel_txt = 'umtsrelation_mnm.txt'
dataf_umts_txt_df = pd.read_csv(hua_umts_dataf_rel_txt, sep=';')
hua_umts_dataf_rel_df_column_index = list(dataf_umts_txt_df.columns)
dataf_umts_txt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
dataf_umts_txt_df.drop(columns=dataf_umts_txt_df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
hua_umts_dataf_rel_df_column_index = dict(zip(list(dataf_umts_txt_df.columns), hua_umts_dataf_rel_df_column_index))
dataf_umts_txt_df.rename(columns=hua_umts_dataf_rel_df_column_index, inplace=True)
#dataf_umts_txt_df.__delitem__(dataf_umts_txt_df.columns[0])
dataf_umts_txt_df.to_csv('umtsrelation_mnm.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')

print(dataf_umts_txt_df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588934/how-to-delete-columns-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first column is the index. Export it without the index with `index=False`:

```
dataf_umts_txt_df.to_csv('umtsrelation_mnm.csv', sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [pandas.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function has a parameter `index`. It defaults to `True` and prints the row names (or your dataframe index) to the csv.

```
index : bool, default True
    Write row names (index).
```

Set `index` to `False`

```
dataf_umts_txt_df.to_csv('umtsrelation_mnm.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```